# how to specify default value of array gorm golang?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I use gorm and postgresql, this is model

```
type Board struct {
    Id     uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;unique" json:"id"`
    Owner  uint `json:"owner"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Contributors []int `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"contributors"`
    GeneratedLink string `gorm:"default:''" json:"generated_link"`
    Todos []TodoStructure `gorm:"type:jsonb;default:[]" json:"todos"`
}

type TodoStructure struct {
    Id string
    Text string
    Completed bool
    Important bool
}
```

in Todo value i specified default value as []
but when i run app i got this error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" (SQLSTATE 42601)
[100.528ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "boards" ("id" bigserial UNIQUE,"owner" bigint,"name" text,"contributors" jsonb,"generated_link" text DEFAULT '',"todos" jsonb DEFAULT [],PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
panic: ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" (SQLSTATE 42601)
```

so how to specify array as default value?

Answer (score 1):

try putting quotes like this  `gorm:"type:jsonb;default:'[]'" json:"todos"`

```
type Board struct {
    Id     uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;unique" json:"id"`
    Owner  uint `json:"owner"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Contributors []int `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"contributors"`
    GeneratedLink string `gorm:"default:''" json:"generated_link"`
    Todos []TodoStructure `gorm:"type:jsonb;default:'[]'" json:"todos"`
}
```

for more reference you can refer this [link](https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html)

Comment: now got the error when trying to create board:  `sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "todos": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]models.TodoStructure`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to include brackets like so:

```
`gorm:"default:('{\"amount\":0,\"currency\":\"USD\"}')"`
```